# Saving ethers in local private testnet

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, wallets

I created a private ethereum tesnet using geth and it runs well on the system. However, I lose all the ethers in my account everytime I close the application. Is there a way to permanently save the testnet ethers on a wallet when is retained?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ganache-cli`](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli) to run a private network and use the `--db` option to save the chain data.

```
ganache-cli --db="/path/to/chaindata/" [other options]
```